# A2 on four A4 pages? | Convert A4 PDF to "A2 on four A4" PDF?

Tags: command-line, pdf, printing, conversion, printer

Given e.g. pdf (in any size) how to enlarge it to A2 size and print on four A4 pages?

(if possible it would be great if pdf having multiple pages we could split like this, so if there is pdf with posters to print multiple at once)

(of course command line solutions proffered ;) )

Comment: Not sure about the second part of your title. Do you mean to say that you want to : 1) blow up a A4 formatted pdf object to A2 and then 2) tile it into 4 A4 pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the pdf A2 format object, crop it with either `pdftilecut` or with `pdfposter`.

- See the `pdftilecut` github page for examples and source code, or consult the man page for `pdftilecut` once installed.
- If you decide to use `pdfposter` to tile your pdf file:

  `$ pdfposter -s4 infile.pdf outfile.pdf`

Both solutions are cli.

Comment: I guess you mean `pip install pdftools.pdfposter` https://pdfposter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Installation.html .

Plus for me `-s1` was needed to split A4 poster into six A4 pages ... hmm... tool does not work perfpectly (or my convert i.svg i.pdf, before cutting), still done the job!

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Tried to help with the little info you provided.  So as you mentioned CLI, no, I did not mean for you to use `$ python -m pip install pdftools.pdfposter` to install that utility. Onto a different subject, I doubt that using a scale factor of 1 (`-s1`) was useful to scale your A4 input format into 6 A4 sheets. `pdfposter -s1 infile.pdf outfile.pdf` will take a given format and output it **unchanged**, plus you had never mentioned scaling to 6 A4 sheets before.  Typo somewhere ?